# What's best way in PySpark to reduce number of output files after shuffle operations?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have a PySpark RDD groupby transformation, which need to shuffle to 10000 partitions to reduce the memory needed for operation on each partition. But after that, I want to write the output to smaller number of files like 100. If I use coalesce on the output, it will automatically change the shuffle operation to 100 which is slow and causing memory error. The other way I have tried is to persist the rdd after groupby (using count() to force the materialization), and then using coalesce. This way achieved what I'm looking for, but it adds overhead of serializing the RDD to the checkpoint on disk. I have also tried using localCheckpoint(), which from my understanding needs to cache/persist the rdd anyway. So I'm wondering if there is any other better approach? In other words, is there way to force the coalesce only happen after certain shuffle operation?

Answer (score 0):

If the you have number of wide transformation in your app and data size is high I would suggest write as it is in temporary location and read it again write it back that will lead to narrow transformation makes faster while writing.Or  you can avoid intermediate writing by calculating shuffle data size in each partition (by default shuffle parrallesim 200) you can increase or decrease this numbers to reduce time.

Comment: I already calculated desired partition count based on data volume, which is large say 10K partitions with 100MB data in each partition. After shuffle and aggregation, the result output is small like 100KB each, so I don't want to have 10K files with 100KB each. Therefore I'd like to coalesce down the partitions without impacting the partitions during shuffling. I have tried the write out, read back and then coalesce. It's just slow. So I'm looking for if there is alternative.